# How to fetch a data from a different table in the databse depending on the outcome of another fetch

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sql

I'm not sure how to word the question but what I'm trying to do is have a jquery autocomplete show some data, now it's already doing so but there's a slight problem.
The way this website is set up is it has products, and suppliers, the suppliers have their own table and are all assigned an id, and the products have a "supplier" row that has a number.
Right now when searching for a product I'm doing this to output the search results:

```
$get_prods = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table`".$showall);
                $get_brand = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table2`");
                $js = "";
                while($prods = mysql_fetch_array($get_prods)){
                    $prodbrand = mysql_fetch_array($get_brand);
                    $js .= "'".addslashes($prodbrand['supplier']).";;".addslashes($prods['sku']).";; ". addslashes($prods['name'])." (".indexStock($prods['id'])." on stock)',";
```

but when you search for a product instead of showing the supplier name it shows the suppliers id number, is there a way to have it fetch the actual supplier name instead?

Comment: I think you need a linking table with supplier name and number, then left join to that using supplier number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want information from multiple tables in the same result set you have to do a SQL join. Here is an example that might help.

```
SELECT * FROM products
INNER JOIN suppliers ON suppliers.suppliersID = products.suppliersID
```

Your result set would then have all the fields from both tables present and would be matched up on the supplier ID in your case.

Comment: I tried:

http://pastebin.com/BUhtwyqT

but it's still just outputting the supplier ID